# React redux toolkit doesn’t trigger component refresh first fetch

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am experimenting with redux-toolkit and migrating a typical TODO app in which I was using the old react-redux version. I have successfully converted it, using createApi service and I am able to add, update and delete todos without problems.
However, I have an issue when I add a new todo the first time, my component doesn't refresh. When manually reload the page, it shows normally and at that point, if I remove it, works properly (also adding/removing new ones).
Reading redux-toolkit documentation, I have also tried using "refetchOnMountOrArgChange" and if I navigate back and forth from in the app without refreshing, refetch is triggered and it is actually showing, but I was wondering if there is a method that always checks if data changes and refresh components or refetch data and I though "currentData" should do the trick, but it doesn't apparently. Any thought/suggestion?

**todoService.js**

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { TODOS_URL } from '../config';

export const todosApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'todos',
  tagTypes: ['TODO'],
  refetchOnMountOrArgChange: 1,
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: TODOS_URL }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getTodos: builder.query({
      query: (list_id = '') => '?list_id=' + list_id,
      providesTags: (result, error) => {
        if (error || !result || !result.data) {
          return [{ type: 'TODO' }];
        }
        return result.data.map((ele) => ({
          type: 'TODO',
          id: ele.id,
        }));
      },
    }),
    deleteTodo: builder.mutation({
      query: (id) => ({
        url: '/' + id,
        method: 'DELETE',
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['TODO'], // (result, error, id) =>  {type:'TODO', id:id})
    }),
    addTodo: builder.mutation({
      query: (todo) => ({
        url: '',
        method: 'POST',
        body: todo,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['TODO'],
    }),
    updateTodo: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ id, ...body }) => ({
        url: '/' + id,
        method: 'PATCH',
        body,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['TODO'],
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useAddTodoMutation,
  useUpdateTodoMutation,
  useGetTodosQuery,
  useDeleteTodoMutation,
} = todosApi;
```

**MyTodos.js component:**

```
import { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import FilterTodo from './FilterTodo';
import Todos from './Todos';
import { filterTodo } from '../../features/todos/filterSlice';
import ErrorBoundary from '../ErrorBoundary';
import {
  useAddTodoMutation,
  useUpdateTodoMutation,
  useGetTodosQuery,
  useDeleteTodoMutation,
} from '../../service/todosService';

import AddTodo from '../AddElement';
import { Link, useLocation, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ArrowLeftCircle } from 'react-bootstrap-icons';

export default function MyTodos() {
  let { list_id } = useParams();
  list_id = Number(list_id);
  // console.log(list_id);
  const { search } = useLocation();
  const pars = new URLSearchParams(search);
  const list_name = pars.get('list_name') ?? '';
  const todoEl = useRef('');
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const activeFilter = useSelector((state) => state.filter);

  const {
    data: { data = [] } = {},
    error,
    isFetching,
  } = useGetTodosQuery(list_id);

  const todos = data.filter((todo) => {
    // ALL
    if (activeFilter === 'ALL') {
      return true;
    }
    // COMPLETED
    if (activeFilter === 'COMPLETED') {
      return todo.completed;
    }
    // DEFAULT TODO
    return !todo.completed;
  });

  const [deleteTodo] = useDeleteTodoMutation();

  const [addTodo, { isSuccess: isAddSuccess }] = useAddTodoMutation({refetchOnMountOrArgChange: true);

  const [updateTodo] = useUpdateTodoMutation();

  const manageClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    addTodo({
      name: todoEl.current.value,
      user_id: 1,
      dueDate: new Date().toLocaleDateString(),
      list_id,
    });
  };

  if (isAddSuccess) {
    todoEl.current.value = '';
  }

  const onFilterTodo = (filter) => {
    dispatch(filterTodo(filter));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) {
      toast.error(error);
    }
    if (isFetching) {
      toast.info('Loading todos...');
    } else {
      toast.dismiss();
    }
    return () => {};
  }, [error, isFetching]);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{list_name}</h1>
      <div className="col-md-6">
        <AddTodo
          Ele={todoEl}
          manageClick={manageClick}
          txtButton={'ADD TODO'}
        />
        <ErrorBoundary>
          <Todos
            todos={todos}
            deleteTodo={deleteTodo}
            updateTodo={updateTodo}
          />
        </ErrorBoundary>
        <FilterTodo filter={activeFilter} onFilter={onFilterTodo} />
        <ToastContainer
          position="top-center"
          autoClose={3000}
          hideProgressBar={false}
          newestOnTop={false}
          closeOnClick
          rtl={false}
          pauseOnFocusLoss
          draggable
          pauseOnHover
        />
        <div className="back btn btn-outline-secondary float-end">
          <Link to="/lists">
            <ArrowLeftCircle />
            <span className="ms-2">GO BACK</span>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you taken at the provided tags etc. in the Redux Devtools in the RTK Query tab?

Comment: Hi @phry and thanks for your answer. Yes I did, it looks like the mutation is executed correctly, fulfilled and payload with data is there actually: type:"todos/executeMutation/fulfilled"
payload >
   data
   name:"My first todo"
          list_id:44
                 duedate:"2022-05-15T20:07:12.679195Z"
                 updated_at:"2022-05-15T20:07:12.000000Z"
                 created_at:"2022-05-15T20:07:12.000000Z"

Comment: The devtools also show you all the provided tags, that's more what I was interested in here :)
But good you got it fixed!

Comment: Oh really? Where can I find provided tags in devtools?

Comment: At the bottom select "RTK Query" and then select "Tags" in the top right.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found out what I was doing wrong. In the getTodos method I was directly returning data before looping through them, instead of checking first for any differences when fetching data to invalidate cache. Plus, as per documentation, https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/automated-refetching#providing-cache-data, using the spread operator on data results and checking todos id fixed it:

**todoService.js**

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { TODOS_URL } from '../config';

export const todosApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'todos',
  tagTypes: ['TODO'],
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: TODOS_URL }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getTodos: builder.query({
      query: (list_id = '') => '?list_id=' + list_id,
      // providesTags: (result, error) => {
      //   if (error || !result || !result.data) {
      //     return [{ type: 'TODO' }];
      //   }
      //   return result.data.map((ele) => ({
      //     type: 'TODO',
      //     id: ele.id,
      //   }));
      // },
      providesTags: (result) =>
        result
          ? [...result.data.map(({ id }) => ({ type: 'TODO', id })), 'TODO']
          : ['TODO'],
    }),
    deleteTodo: builder.mutation({
      query: (id) => ({
        url: '/' + id,
        method: 'DELETE',
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['TODO'], // (result, error, id) =>  {type:'TODO', id:id})
    }),
    addTodo: builder.mutation({
      query: (todo) => ({
        url: '',
        method: 'POST',
        body: todo,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['TODO'],
    }),
    updateTodo: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ id, ...body }) => ({
        url: '/' + id,
        method: 'PATCH',
        body,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['TODO'],
    }),
  }),
});

export const {
  useAddTodoMutation,
  useUpdateTodoMutation,
  useGetTodosQuery,
  useDeleteTodoMutation,
} = todosApi;
```